# Maven profile properties are not "overriding"

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have Maven multi-module project with such structure:

> parent-pom-project
>
> -- module1
>
> -- module2

At the parent-pom-project I have such pom.xml

```
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>
...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
           <id>local</id>
           <properties>
               <prop>local_prop</prop>
           </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
           <id>test</id>
           <modules>
                <module>module2</module>
           </modules>
           <properties>
               <prop>test_prop</prop>
           </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

At all pom.xml files I have such tag:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

At module1 and module2 in *resource* directory I have properties files with such text:

```
prop=${prop}
```

The problem is that after

> mvn clean install

or

> mvn clean install -Ptest

or even

> mvn clean install -P test

I get

> prop=local_prop

If I user test profile for build module2 is also builded, but properties are used from local profile.
I use Maven 3.0.3. 
Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not define the property outside of any profile node?

Comment: In fact I think that you could try to define the property outside of any profile node with an empty value. -->            <properties>
               <prop></prop>
           </properties>

Comment: 2 bugske Yes - I double check it. And I try yours second idea - nothing changes.

Comment: Are you executing the `mvn` command from your parent module directory ?

Comment: Hmm i have got the same problem :/ 
Have you find any solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem uninstalling current maven plugin for eclipse and use another one.
Now I use this ones:
- Maven Integration: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
- Maven Integration for WTP: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras/

Early I was using this one http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/. I cannot explain such behavior but may be some configuration was changed by plugin.

Comment: Weird... Sounds like an other bug in the m2 plugin...
(your third link is broken by the way)

Comment: use this url in Eclipse (Help->Install New Software)

Comment: (I am IntelliJ user). oh ok, I should have read it a bit longer ;) ("This is an Eclipse Update site/p2 repository; you must access it from Eclipse")... Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

You could try to use the **mvn help:effective-pom -Ptest** command to see the paramters used in your build.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/plugin-info.html for more details.

Answer (score 9):

Add a `${basedir}` in front of your resource directories:

`<directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>`

This should fix your problem. My explanation would be that in a multi-module project it's not picking up the path correctly (for within the child module), if you're building from the top-level. Thus when trying to filter, it applies it to a different directory (the actual root-level aggregator), instead of the child.

I hope it helps.

Comment: After long time digging into this, that fixed my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @carlspring Could this mentioned resolution be the answer to my problem you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606666/passing-environment-variables-to-config-properties-file-via-maven

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out how maven can resolve your property if you do not specify any profile. So, to see what's really there, I tried myself, following exactly the schema you described and... I did not experience the problem you have. In your case, it really behaves like if the property was defined outside the profile -as bugske suggested. What happened if you comment temporarily both profiles ?

Answer (score 0):

Although old I had the same problem and didn't find the solution here. For me the problem was Eclipse which I use parallel to mvn on the command line. Eclipse instantly called process-resources after I did so on the command line.

Thus the solution was to select the profile in Eclipse (Project->Maven->Select Maven Profiles).