# Define different value per profile for same Maven property

Tags: maven

I'm facing a problem with maven property per profiles. I have two profiles, each one has the same property 'prop.key' with different values. When I call `mvn clean package -PA -PB` or `mvn clean package -PB -PA` both are using the same value '*B-1.0-SNAPSHOT*'. I'm using maven 3.0.4.

Below my POM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <prop.key>UNKNOWN</prop.key>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>A</id>
            <properties>
                <prop.key>A-${project.version}</prop.key>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>A</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks name="a" description="a-desc">
                                        <echo message="RUN A = ${prop.key}" level="info"/>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>B</id>
            <properties>
                <prop.key>B-${project.version}</prop.key>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>B</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks name="b" description="b-desc">
                                        <echo message="RUN B = ${prop.key}" level="info"/>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have found ['similar topic'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310545/maven-profile-properties-are-not-overriding) but with opposite result!
Is it a bug or a feature of maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write 
    `mvn package -PA,B`
for short.

The result is the same:
    `[echo] RUN A = B-1.0-SNAPSHOT` and
    `[echo] RUN B = B-1.0-SNAPSHOT`

This is the correct behaviour of maven.

One property can only have one specific value per run. You can overwrite a "default value" with a version in a profile. But if you redefine it in two profiles and activate both, one of the profiles "wins".

It is not possible to have one value per profile for one and the same property. Profiles do not have their own variable scope. Properties are always global.

Comment: Marc von Renteln, tank you for your comment. It is possible to use filtering and *.properties files, but it wont help in my case. I have found workaround which is copying dir with current result.

Comment: @Marc, how do you decide which profile "wins"? Is it the sequence of passing parameters to `-P` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you get this behavior because last parameter for profile gets picked.
Try

```
mvn clean package -PA,B
```

See [Maven introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

> Profiles can be explicitly specified using the -P CLI option.
>
> This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of
>   profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, no profiles other
>   than those specified in the option argument will be activated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `mvn package -PA,B`, maven will read both profiles A and B, and the properties from later one in the pom.xml file will take precedence (B is defined below A in pom.xml), result in `<prop.key>B-${project.version}</prop.key>` will be used.