# Passing environment variables to config.properties file via maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a java config.properties file which reads as follows:

```
mosURL=${mosURL}
mopURL=${mopURL}
```

I am wanting to pass in the values to `${mosURL}` and `${mopURL}` when I initiate my build with Maven. These properties are environment specific URL's.

My POM file is below and you can see I have set up property profiles for each environment. **(EDIT. POM Example now contains suggestted changes mentioned in Anser below.)** I have set env-uat as my default by having                 `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` present in the env-uat section.

But when I run mvn test everyting starts off as expected but when the test fails when attempting to use the URL and I get an error to inform me that no URL is present. So somewhere the link of passing from pom.xml into config.properties isnt working.

I can run "mvn help:active-profiles" from command and I can see the following:

```
The following profiles are active:

 - env-uat (source: com.mycompany.app:my-app:1)
```

Is there a missing link that I dont know about?

**EDIT:** I can run `mvn resources:resources` and when I look at the generated .properties file in the target/classes folder I can see that all the properties are listed correctly as I would expect. But they are not being passed into my java propeties.config file when I run 'mvn test'.

I have started reading about Spring and wondering if I need to configure something with Spring to get these values form Maven into my Java file? The Maven population of the properties look fine.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <properties>
                <mosURL>https://mos-uat.mywebsiteurlishere.com</mosURL>
                <mopURL>https://mop-uat.mywebsiteurlishere.com/</mopURL>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-xpath</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2.jre9-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <exclude>**/*TPOS_Run_All.java</exclude>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>env-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mosURL>https://mos-dev.mywebsiteurlishere.com</mosURL>
                <mopURL>https://mop-dev.mywebsiteurlishere.com/</mopURL>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>env-uat</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <mosURL>https://mos-uat.mywebsiteurlishere.com</mosURL>
                <mopURL>https://mop-uat.mywebsiteurlishere.com/</mopURL>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here should be connected to the "default" value of your variables.

Try adding the properties in the global properties declaration, on the top of your pom

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <properties>
        //add them here aswell
        <mosURL>https://mos-dev.mywebsiteurlishere.com</mosURL>
        <mopURL>https://mop-dev.mywebsiteurlishere.com/</mopURL>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

I have the same configuration as yours, and the only difference seems to be this one.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This section at the top is not a child of an environment such as env-dev or env-uat, so the question here is which URL's do I add in? In the example you created you added in the dev ones, but what about uat ones?

Comment: This is the default value of your variable: if a `profile` is used while running the project, maven will override that value with the one in the profile section. I'm supposing that if he doesn't find a default value, something could not work as expected. Have you tried with this solution?

Comment: I see, the above makes sense now. I just tried though with the new properties populated and failing with same problem.

Comment: are you sure that the resourse is read correctly? If you replace in config.properties `mosURL=${mosURL}` with `mosUrl=https://mos-dev.mywebsiteurlishere.com` does it works?

Comment: Wondering if its location or name of confg.properties. It looks to be in the expected place which is directly under src/Test/Resources.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that! Mine is under src - main -> resources , but I only use that for production, not for testing

Comment: My test code is expecting my config.properties to be in the Test folder so I would have to fiddle about a bit to point the code to src/Main/resources. I'm going to look to see if it has to be configured in pom.xml

Comment: If it works tell me that I'll add that to the answer ;)

Comment: Nope. Still stuck. Sad face.

Comment: I've tried in test folder a JUnit in my project, and it worked (I didn't move the config.properties file, it's still in main). Can you please add in the question how you get the properties from `config.properties` ? Maybe the problem is there

Comment: It looks like getting the properties from config.properties is working fine as when I hardcode a URL in config.properties, the code works as I expect. The issue seems to be that Maven is not passing in a property from pom.xml into config.properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer in case it's useful to anyone who may stumble across this in future.

After a discussion with the CI developer we decided that holding system specific values in my framework was the wrong approach. The property values are best held outside of Maven and let the CI environment pass them in on build. So I stripped out all environment specific properties from my POM.

I then created a separate class with static return methods to hold each of my config values such as below:

```
public class Config {

public static String getUrl1() {
    return System.getProperty("url1");
}

public static String getUrl2() {
    return System.getProperty("url2");
}
}
```

My code that would read these properties would be as simple as:

```
String strUrl1 = Config.getUrl1();
```

I would pass in the actual value from Maven comand such as:

```
mvn clean test -Durl1=https://url1goeshere.com/ -Durl2=https://url2goeshere
```

So it is then up to our CI developers to hold and pass in my specific variables. We are holding the environment values in Octopus which will then pass it to placeholders in TeamCity that will then construct and pass a command to Maven. So when we deploy to Dev through Octopus it will know to pass in the Dev parameters and so on for other environments.